# mysql how to show order number in result

Tags: mysql, sql

so here is the query

```
select * from test order by pow(c1 - 8, 2) + pow(c2 - 5, 2) limit 3
```

is there any way to show order section -> "pow(c1 - 8, 2) + pow(c2 - 5, 2)" for each record in result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just include it in the `select`:

```
select t.*, pow(c1 - 8, 2) + pow(c2 - 5, 2) as distance_squared
from test t
order by distance_squared
limit 3
```